# New dataframe merging two df that repeats values from 1st df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have one dataframe in the form (with some other columns which aren't very relevant to the question)-

| Max Date | Stock |
| --- | --- |
| 28-09-2026 | A |
| 22-03-2024 | B |
| 17-10-2023 | C |
| 17-05-2025 | D |

I have another dataframe with only a list of dates. For each date in the 2nd dataframe, I want to create a repeat of each stock and each "max date" from 1st dataframe in order to compare against that date and assign a classification based on whether the date is earlier or later.

Output should be like -

| Date (2nd df) | Stock | Max Date | Classification |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-02-2023 | A | 28-09-2026 | Lower |
| 10-03-2025 | A | 28-09-2026 | Lower |
| 01-02-2023 | B | 22-03-2024 | Lower |
| 10-03-2025 | B | 22-03-2024 | Higher |

I tried using pd.merge() after bringing in the Stock names into the 2nd dataframe and doing a left or an outer join.

```
df2['Stock'] = df1['Stock'][:1]
new_df = pd.merge(df2, df1, on  = 'Stock', how = 'outer')
print(new_df)
```

However, the "Max Dates" from 1st dataframe don't populate in the merged dataframe. Is there an easier way to do this?

Also tried the following-

```
new_df = pd.concat([df2, df1, axis =1, join = 'outer')
```

The above is a simple join, but i want rows from df1 repeated for every date entry in df2.

So let's say in the 2nd dataframe, there are n dates, the new dataframe should have these dates and all columns from 1st dataframe repeated n times for each date in 2nd dataframe (for each Stock).

Edit: Please note that the 2nd dataframe has only a list of dates. It doesn't have the list of Stocks, which could potentially be used as common key to do a merge. However, I'm not sure how to bring in Stock name and make it repeat for every date in the 2nd df.

Comment: You can try `pd.merge(df1, df2, how="cross")`.

Comment: that doesn't work since to start with i dont have a common key. I need to create a repeat of "Stock" for each date in 2nd df and then i can merge. I'm not sure how to create this repeat. Even the "Merging 101" link doesnt have the answer

Comment: Have you tried it? There is no common key with `how="cross"`.

Comment: yes i did- it gives an error: "MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on"

Comment: It may be an issue with pandas version. `how="cross"` was introduced in 1.2.0.